# Oracle Dataguard, Conexion automatica del cliente a la base de datos primaria despues de hacerse failover

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy montando Oracle Database 19c con Dataguard y no consigo encontrar la manera de hacer que las conexiones del cliente vayan automaticamente a la base de datos primaria aunque se haya hecho failover, solo consigo que la conexion cambie a la nueva primaria una vez hecho failover y ya se haya establecido la conexion, pero una vez hecho dicho failover, cuando intento conectar a la misma entrada de tnsnames.ora, me lleva a la que  es ahora la standby.

Explico un poco la configuracion de listener y tnsnames:

Tengo una base de datos (db1_a) con un listener para el servicio del cliente y otro exclusivo para el Dataguard en nodo1, y una base de datos (db1_b) con dos listener tambien, uno parra el servicio  y otro para el dataguard

#### LISTENER

HOST A

```
LISTENER_DG = 
  (DESCRIPTION= 
    (ADDRESS_LIST= 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST=dbhost-a) (PORT=1522))
      )
  )
SID_LIST_LISTENER_DG= 
  (SID_LIST= 
    (SID_DESC= 
      (SID_NAME=db1) 
      (SDU=32767) 
      (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.1.0/db_1) 
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=db1_a_static.demo.org) 
    ) 
    (SID_DESC= 
      (SID_NAME=db1) 
      (SDU=32767) 
      (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.1.0/db_1) 
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=db1_a_dgmgrl.demo.org) 
      ) 
  )

LISTENER_DB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbhost-a)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC22))
    )
  )
SID_LIST_LISTENER_DB1 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db1.demo.org)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/19.1.0/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db1)
    )
  )
```

HOST B

```
LISTENER_DG = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp) (HOST = dbhost-b) (PORT = 1522)) 
      ) 
  ) 
SID_LIST_LISTENER_DG = 
  (SID_LIST = 
    (SID_DESC = 
      (SID_NAME = db1) 
      (SDU = 32767) 
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.1.0/db_1) 
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db1_b_static.demo.org) 
    ) 
    (SID_DESC = 
      (SID_NAME = db1) 
      (SDU = 32767) 
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.1.0/db_1) 
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db1_b_dgmgrl.demo.org) 
      ) 
  )

LISTENER_DB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbhost-b)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC22))
    )
  )
SID_LIST_LISTENER_DB1 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db1.demo.org)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/19.1.0/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db1)
    )
  )
```

#### TNSNAMES.ORA

EN AMBOS NODOS

```
db1_a = 
    (description = (SDU = 32767) 
        (address_list= 
            (address = (protocol = tcp) (host = dbhost-a) (port = 1522))) 
    (connect_data = 
        (service_name = db1_a.demo.org) 
        (server = dedicated))) 
        
        
db1_b = 
    (description = (SDU = 32767) 
        (address_list = 
            (address = (protocol = tcp) (host = dbhost-b) (port = 1522))) 
    (connect_data = 
        (service_name = db1_b.demo.org) 
        (server=dedicated))) 
        
        
db1_a_static = 
    (description = (SDU = 32767) 
        (address_list = 
            (address = (protocol = tcp) (host = dbhost-a) (port = 1522))) 
    (connect_data = 
        (service_name = db1_a_static.demo.org) 
        (server=dedicated))) 
        
        
db1_b_static = 
    (description = (SDU = 32767) 
        (address_list = 
            (address = (protocol = tcp) (host = dbhost-b) (port = 1522))) 
    (connect_data = 
        (service_name = db1_b_static.demo.org) 
        (server = dedicated)))
```

#### TNSNAMES.ORA CLIENTE

```
db1 = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (FAILOVER = on)
      (LOAD_BALANCE = off)
      (SOURCE_ROUTE = off)
      (ADDRESS = 
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST = dbhost-a)
        (PORT = 1522)
      )
      (ADDRESS = 
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST = dbhost-b)
        (PORT = 1522)
      )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (FAILOVER_MODE = 
        (TYPE = session)
        (METHOD = basic)
        (RETRIES = 180)
        (DELAY = 5)
      )
      (SERVER = dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db1.demo.org)
    )
  )
```

Una vez montado el dataguard y funcionando correctamente; creo un servico adicional con el paquete DBMS para usarle a modo de balanceador, es decir, que este activo solo cuando el DATABASE_ROLE de la base de datos sea PRIMARY:

```
begin
  DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE (
    service_name => 'db1.demo.org',
    network_name => 'db1.demo.org',
    aq_ha_notifications => true,
    failover_method =>'BASIC',
    failover_type => 'SELECT',
    failover_retries => 180,
    failover_delay => 1
  );
end;
/
```

y ademas creo en la base de datos un trigger para que funcione:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYS.bd_failover_trig after startup on database
DECLARE
    role VARCHAR(30);
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      DATABASE_ROLE
    INTO
      role
    FROM
      V$DATABASE;
    IF role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
      DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE('db1.demo.org');
    ELSE
      DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE('db1.demo.org');
    END IF;
  END;
/
```

Confirmo que el servicio esta activo solo en la base de datos primaria con la select de la vista de v$active_services:

```
SELECT name,network_name FROM v$active_services ORDER BY 1;
```

Podrian ayudarme, o haciendome ver que es lo que hago mal, porque por mas que busco y leo documentacion y foros, no consigo dar con la solucion, o quiza no la haya entendido.

Gracias  a todos de antemano.

Un saludo